# Converting a list of strings to column names in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have the following statement, using tuples in Python to make the query:

```
select ('column1', 'column2', 'column3')::text from table limit 10;
```

I would like this to become:

```
select (column1, column2, column3)::text from table limit 10
```

The `::text` is because the columns are bools, and I want them represented as an array, but before doing that, I need to get rid of the parenthesis and I have no idea how.

Comment: Are you aware that `(column1, column2, column3)::text` does not create an array, but an anonymous record type which is then cast to `text`?

Comment: Why don't you simply remove the single quotes in Python when you create that statement?

Comment: the returned value is (t,f,f), which works well for me. You mean convert the tuple to a string and replace the parenthesis? How did i miss that? 12 hours into a coding hole i think it's time to stop. Thank you kind sir/madam.